# How can I add images in list widget in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

[image: tartube image which is written in pygtk]

Simply what I am trying to achieve is a thumbnail and some data like shown above the image as an item in ListWidget in PyQt5.

I have the URL of a thumbnail and all the data like title, channel name, etc.

I am able to get the title in a list widget by doing this:

```
titles = ['title1','title2']
self.listWidget.addItems(titles)
```

The design is created by Qt Designer and converted to python using pyuic5.

This is my first question in StackOverflow. Also, I know that I should share code but code is normally generated by pyuic5 in which there is only listWidget (item based).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put images with text in your QListWidget you need to combine QIcon with Text into a QListWidgetItem like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import os

icon_path = os.getcwd() + "\icon.jpg"
titles = ['title1','title2']

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setupUi(self) 
        #add list of strings
        self.listWidget.addItems(titles)
        #create QIcon
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(icon_path)
        #Create the row with Icon + Text
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(icon, "Hello this is a test")
        #set size of the item
        size = QtCore.QSize()
        size.setHeight(100)
        size.setWidth(400)
        item.setSizeHint(size)
        #Put the item into the widget
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And you will get something like this:

[image: Example]